# Simplest method of passing one php variable in a url

Tags: php, variables

I have examined various discussions about how to pass php variable in a url but haven't seen any with the simple situation I'm interested in. Also I would like to be absolutely sure I'm getting an up-to-date solution.

In a digital book, I want to link to mypage2.php and include a variable $video. How do I pass this variable safely, and how do I "detect" $video and its current value of "oil-spill"?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you not have any code to show us so we can examine and possibly give you a better alternative?

Comment: I said I want to creae a link in my ebook. I realize with the printf comment from the other helpful person that we have perhaps missed the simplicity of my need. This a simple text link in an ebook, a reading document, no code involved. But the variable $video exists in the target php page, where it needs to be able to process the value, in this case "oil-spill". I was hoping to see a clear example of what the link for the url would look like, with the variable and value provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a link like:

```
printf('<a href="mypage2.php?video=%s">Link</a>', htmlspecialchars($video, ENT_COMPAT));
```

On `mypage2.php`, check if the query parameter is in the URL:

```
if (!isset($_GET['video'])) {
    die('I need that query parameter!');
}

$video = $_GET['video'];
```

Comment: Okay, I will experiment with that tomorrow, and thank you very much for helping me out!

Comment: So I guess %s would be replaced with my value oil-spill without quotes? This is strictly a hard text link in a digital book.

Comment: Well then you just need `<a href="mypage2.php?video=oil-spill">`. The above code is for dynamically creating such a link with guaranteed valid syntax.

Comment: Thank you very much. I do also appreciate that fuller example of syntax in a coding context.