# Accessing a POST variable in another PHP File

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms, variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simplest method of passing one php variable in a url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14331479/simplest-method-of-passing-one-php-variable-in-a-url)

I am making a quiz application. At the faculty end, teachers get to type the topic name (with which I will form a vanity URL), and type 3 questions with possible options including answer in one of them. Everytime a teacher creates a quiz, a new table will be created with the questions, options and answers everytime.

My db.php file:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("quiz");
?>
```

My faculty.php file:

```
<form action="fac_handler.php" method="POST">
Quiz Topic:<br><input type="text" name="topic"><br><br>Enter Questions:<br><br>
<?php
$a="a";
$b="b";
$c="c";
$d="d";
for ($i=1; $i<=3;$i++) 
{ 
?>
Question <?php echo $i?>:<br>
<textarea type="text" name="<?php echo "q".$i;?>"></textarea><br>
<br>
<input type="text" name="<?php echo $a.$i; ?>">&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="text" name="<?php echo $b.$i; ?>">&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="text" name="<?php echo $c.$i; ?>">&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="text" name="<?php echo $d.$i; ?>">&nbsp;&nbsp;<br><hr>
<?php
}
?>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

My fac_handler.php file:

```
<?php
require "db.php";

if(isset($_POST['topic']) && !empty($_POST['topic']))
{
$topic=$_POST['topic'];

if(isset($_POST['q1'])&&isset($_POST['a1'])&&isset($_POST['b1'])&&isset($_POST['c1'])&&isset($_POST['d1'])) 
{
if(!empty($_POST['q1']) && !empty($_POST['a1']) && !empty($_POST['b1']) && !empty($_POST['c1']) && !empty($_POST['d1'])) 
{
$q1=$_POST['q1'];
$a1a=$_POST['a1'];
$a1b=$_POST['b1'];
$a1c=$_POST['c1'];
$a1d=$_POST['d1'];  
}
else
{
    echo "Please Set the Questions and the Options!";
    die();
}
} 
if(isset($_POST['q2'])&&isset($_POST['a2'])&&isset($_POST['b2'])&&isset($_POST['c2'])&&isset($_POST['d2']))
{
if(!empty($_POST['q2']) && !empty($_POST['a2']) && !empty($_POST['b2']) && !empty($_POST['c2']) && !empty($_POST['d2']))
{
$q2=$_POST['q2'];
$a2a=$_POST['a2'];
$a2b=$_POST['b2'];
$a2c=$_POST['c2'];
$a2d=$_POST['d2'];  
}
else
{
    echo "Please Set the Questions and the Options!";
    die();
}
}
if(isset($_POST['q3'])&&isset($_POST['a3'])&&isset($_POST['b3'])&&isset($_POST['c3'])&&isset($_POST['d3']))
{
if(!empty($_POST['q3']) && !empty($_POST['a3']) && !empty($_POST['b3']) && !empty($_POST['c3']) && !empty($_POST['d3']))
{
$q3=$_POST['q3'];
$a3a=$_POST['a3'];
$a3b=$_POST['b3'];
$a3c=$_POST['c3'];
$a3d=$_POST['d3'];  
}
else
{
    echo "Please Set the Questions and the Options!";
    die();
}
}  
$ans1=$a1a;
$ans2=$a2a;
$ans3=$a3a;

$qtbname="q_".$topic;
$top=$_SESSION['topic']=serialize($_POST['topic']);
$new="q_".$top;

$create_table="CREATE TABLE $qtbname(id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,question VARCHAR(500),answer VARCHAR(30),optiona VARCHAR(30),optionb VARCHAR(30),optionc VARCHAR(30),optiond VARCHAR(30),PRIMARY KEY (id))";
mysql_query($create_table);

$query1="INSERT INTO $qtbname VALUES('','$q1','$ans1','$a1a','$a1b','$a1c','$a1d')";
$query2="INSERT INTO $qtbname VALUES('','$q2','$ans2','$a2a','$a2b','$a2c','$a2d')";
$query3="INSERT INTO $qtbname VALUES('','$q3','$ans3','$a3a','$a3b','$a3c','$a3d')";

$result1=mysql_query($query1);
$result2=mysql_query($query2);
$result3=mysql_query($query3);

header("Location: student.php");
}
else
{
    echo "Please Set the Quiz Topic";
}
?>
```

Now as you can see, after the table gets created dynamically everytime with a table prefix, it gets redirected to student.php file which looks like this.

My student.php file:

```
<?php
require "db.php";

$query="SELECT * FROM $new";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$n="1";
$i="a";

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
echo "Question ".$n." : ".$row['question'];
echo "<br>";
$ansr=$row['answer'];
?>
<form action="std_handler.php" method="POST">
<input type="radio" name="<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['optiona']; ?>"><?php echo $row['optiona']; ?>
<input type="radio" name="<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['optionb']; ?>"><?php echo $row['optionb']; ?>
<input type="radio" name="<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['optionc']; ?>"><?php echo $row['optionc']; ?>
<input type="radio" name="<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['optiond']; ?>"><?php echo $row['optiond']; ?><br>
<?php
++$i;
++$n;
}
?>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The fourth line in this student.php file, the query, **$query="SELECT * FROM $new";**, I need to access the table which I just created at the faculty end to display the questions and answers in text and radio button format.

Here is my std_handler.php file:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['a']))
{
$ans=$_POST['a'];
echo $ans;
echo "<br>";
}
if(isset($_POST['b']))
{
$ans=$_POST['b'];
echo $ans;
echo "<br>";
}
if(isset($_POST['c']))
{
$ans=$_POST['c'];
echo $ans;
echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

In the faculty handler file, after the validations, I tried to use session and get the variable, I tried to make it global, I tried serializing it, I couldn't succeed to use and select the dynamic table name in the student.php page.

What I want is, as soon as I get redirected to the student.php page, I want to select the table instantly created earlier, how do I do that? How do I access that variable with which I created the table and executed the query at the faculty end?

I keep getting this error: **Notice: Undefined variable: new in C:\xampp\htdocs\quiz\student.php on line 4**

Please help me solve this problem. Thank you.

Comment: Don't create a new table for each quiz! Learn about database normalization.

Comment: I am making this for my university, so there will be hell lot of quizzes made from time to time by the teachers. And I am going to store the results in another table. But I will give it a thought about DB normalization.

Comment: And my question is not a duplicate of that link you gave. It is entirely different I believe. I am not talking of passing a php variable in a url here. I am asking about how to use a variable in a query of another php file.

Comment: I translate the error for you: $new doesn't have a value. So pass it to the page?

Comment: I understood what the error meant Sir. It's just that I am struggling to solve my problem I have mentioned above. My code is not right, I need some help with fixing it.

Comment: Can you send the variable in the url? test.nl?test=hello. Access with $_GET["test"]; //this will be hello.

Comment: header("Location: student.php?new=blabla"); access on other page with $_GET["new"]

Comment: Sometimes you have to stop and start again. Hate to say it this is one of those times. 

Use normalization (i.e. 1 table for all quiz's) and performance, structure, problem solving, reporting, security will be massively improved.

Comment: @tim.baker: Sure, I will try that way definitely but after I get this problem solved. I want to learn to rectify my existing mistake.

Comment: Can I also say please please please look at this, I can't see that you are cleaning you variables, which leaves you wide open to attacks.

Comment: Okay, don't mind asking how do I rectify that problem here then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want something like this:

**Bad solution, but you can see how to pass a variable**

In fac_handler.php:

Change

```
header("Location: student.php");
```

to

```
header("Location: student.php?url=". urlencode($new));
```

On the student page:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM " . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["url"]);
```

This is a method, but if I where you I would do this on an other way.

**How I would do this**

Create a ID that you send and resolve that name to the ride database name.

Comment: I thought about the ID thing earlier too. I am making this with my friend. Anyways, I changed my header to what you said and I replaced that query with the one you gave. I still get that notice I mentioned above about undefined variable.

Comment: Nearly solved, I am getting a new warning: 
Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\quiz\student.php on line 9

Comment: @trollster That means that the query failed. Use this:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php For example: $result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

Comment: Or when you want a nice error msg: this: $result = mysql_query($query) or die("<b>fatal error</b><br />Query: " . $query . "<br />Error: " . mysql_errno() . " " . mysql_error());

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':5:\"aaaaa\"' at line 1

Comment: Could you echo the query? echo $query . "<br/>"; and post it here. Because I can't see what that :5: is.

Comment: SELECT * FROM q_s:8:\"78798789\";You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':8:\"78798789\"' at line 1

Comment: Those numbers are my topic name which I am passing int he url. I suppose it is happening because of that url encode or something? Because the table gets created with q_"name" but urlencode is making the link "q_"someothercrapwithname" so my query is not able to find this table.

Comment: What is that q_s:8:? I guess q_ is the prefix? And you used _s:8:"78798789” as name? I would delete those: “ in a database name. Ad ` around the database name:

SELECT * FROM `q_s:8:78798789`; Edit: didn't read your 2nd command. But you can decode it: urldecode();

Comment: Okay, I solved my problem. I am adding a new answer. I solved it with your help only. Thanks a ton Sir. :)

Comment: No problem. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess I would say this. When it gives you this error: **Notice: Undefined variable: new in C:\xampp\htdocs\quiz\student.php on line 4** it's because it's just that. If we look at the code here:

```
require "db.php";

$query="SELECT * FROM $new";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$n="1";
$i="a";
```

this is your student.php ^^^

You are not setting the value of $new.

So you need to actually define the value.

```
$new = $_GET['x'];
$query="SELECT * FROM $new";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$n="1";
$i="a";
```

Where x is whatever you are passing as your query value.

or something along those lines.

Comment: I want to access the table name which I am creating dynamically everytime at the faculty end.

Comment: Let me give that a shot.

Comment: Refer to @Laurence for passing a variable and then get whatever you are passing. But I agree with him I would personally do it another way.

Comment: So $new = $_GET['url'] I believe. @trollster

Comment: @trollster No Problem. Good luck with the rest of your project.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I solved this problem, this is what I did.

I removed these two from the fac_handler.php page:

```
$top=$_SESSION['topic']=serialize($_POST['topic']);
$new="q_".$top;
```

And few lined below, I changed the header location to:

```
header("Location: student.php?url=".$qtbname);
```

And in the student.php page, I changed my query to:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM " . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["url"]);
```

For the last two modifications above, I sincerely thank Lawrence. Also Thunda thanks a lot for giving me that idea to use the GET variable thing too.

deceze and tim.baker (there in the comments): Thanks a lot for your advice too, now that I solved my problem, I will go ahead with normalization as you suggested.

Thanks a lot stackoverflow, was struggling with this for a long time.